Double derivative of concave $F$ is negative? $(x-y)\cdot\nabla F(x)=0$ implies $\partial_{x-y}\partial_{x-y}F(x)<0$?
$F:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ is a strictly concave. $\nabla$ is gradient. $x,y,z\in\mathbb R^n$
Then, is it possible to prove that:
$(x-y)\cdot\nabla F(x)=0$ implies $\partial_{x-y}\partial_{x-y}F(x)<0$?
Here $\partial_{x-y}$ is the directional derivative.
I think this result must be correct. In one-dimension, the double derivative of strictly concave function is negative. Also, in high dimensions, the Hessian is negative.
Intuitively, since the gradient is zero, the point $x$ can be view as an optimal point. We are taking a double derivative at the optimal point in the tangent directions.

The second derivative of a strictly concave function is $\le 0$, but can be zero at some points. Example: $f(x) = -x^4$ at $x=0$.
